# Parse numbers from strings and detect which string is number

Tags: javascript

I have script that should convert strings to numbers when string actually is number.

First I tried `isNumber(x)`, but it doesnt work on string that look like numbers, but actually are not, e.g. agreement number with leading zero '035859':

```
   if (isNumber('035859')) {
      parseFloat('035859'); //35859
   }
```

Next I tried parsing and comparing strings after parse and I got opposite problem - some numbers were not recognized as numbers

```
 if (parseFloat('2.00').toString() == '2.00') //false
```

What should I do to find all numbers, but skip all strings? May be someone familiar with global approach without coding all possible exceptions?

Comment: For your second example, `parseFloat('2.00').toString() == '2'` (integers and floats both belong to the `number` type in JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could design a regular expression that only matches what you regard a number (a subset of what `parseFloat` would convert to number):

```js
function toNumber(s) {
    return /^-?([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d+)?$/.test(s) ? +s : s;
}

console.log(typeof toNumber('2.00')); // number
console.log(typeof toNumber('0472638')); // string
```

Comment: Looks like that's what I was lookig for. Tests run perfect

Answer (score 4):

`parseFloat` and `parseInt` both return `NaN` if the input string could not be converted to a number. You can test for `NaN` with the `isNaN` function:

```
var number = parseFloat( input );
if( isNaN( number ) {
    // not a number
}
else {
    // is a number
}
```

There's also the special-case of `Infinity` which you may want to test for as well:

```
var number = parseFloat( input );
if( !isNaN( number ) && isFinite( number ) ) {
    // is a number that is not infinity:


}
```

You could save trouble by having your own simple wrapper function that returns `null` on failure:

```
function getNumber( input ) {

    var number = parseFloat( input );
    if( !isNaN( number ) && isFinite( number ) ) return number;
    return null;
}
```

Used like so:

```
var number = getNumber( input );
if( number != null ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: `parseInt` and  `parseFloat` returns the leading numbers in case of a string which contains both leading numbers and non-string values. It returns `NaN` only if the first character can't be converted to number. So output of `parseInt("12345L")` would be `12345`. Therefore, the recommended way is to use the  method `Number.isNaN() `